# Can the longer comment bug be fixed?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, comments, design

Single-line comments show like two lines, simply to give space for the Vote and Flag icons, which are placed with above the other.

Can these buttons be placed next to each other? This would allow single-line comments to look like single lines.

### Example:

[image]

Comment: With FGITW no check mark revolver is meant!

Comment: Did you save up all these questions until clock off?

Comment: @random - Can't say. I don't really know how sophisticated my brain is.

Comment: FGITW: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533

Comment: -1 for no drop shadows.

Comment: -1 for no freehand circles! You ruined true art btw!

Comment: You have ruined the wonderful picture. I was going to print and it stick it on my fridge.

Comment: -1 for soulless rectangles

Comment: You have ruined the wonderful fridge.  i was going to magnetize it and stick it on my picture.

Comment: Fine guys, now that your soulful image is back, vote up!

Comment: @Jeremy: Repwhore!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really have a problem with it being vertical and tacking on an extra line, but I probably wouldn't be opposed to it all on one line either. My only thought would be about it potentially increasing the amount of misclicks and accidental flags given out on comments (since it is easier to visually distinguish things vertically than horizontally).

Answer (score 3):

Most people have problems hitting the correct button anyway. Especially while giggling. Putting them next to each other would increase this problem.

Comment: They are anyways next to each other. Just that now they shall be buddies instead of building blocks.

Comment: Up/Down is easier than left/right.

Comment: @LadybugKiller Thanks. I realized this first time!

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to demand that everyone write longer comments.  Despite all the hassle this will cause most of us, this is a definite win for [Welbog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19502#19502).

[Also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21164/can-the-longer-comment-bug-be-fixed/21166#21166), it is easier to visually distinguish things vertically than horizontally.

Comment: Hassle? The buttons will be just as far from each other as they are now.

Comment: Whatchu talkin' 'bout, Rudd?

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't have a problem writing terse comments. Neither do I.

Comment: If Jon Skeet jumped off a bridge, I hope you'd follow him. Then we'd be free of two of you short-commenters. You guys are making a mockery of Jeff and the SO Team by failing to take advantage of everything they have given us. He upped the comment length on meta just for us, you insensitive clod! Jeff's upstairs in his room crying like a little girl because you won't use the things he works so hard to create. Do you think it's funny when a grown man cries? Because that's what you're doing to Jeff.  He is wailing and rending his garments. Quit tormenting the poor man; what did he ever do to you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems entirely unnecessary to me. And honestly, I think it would be more annoying if it changed for single line comments vs multi line comments.

Comment: It can be the same for both.

Comment: See the updated pic above.

Comment: I see, but I'm with John Smithers "Up/Down is easier than left/right"