# Single line comment leaves one line's gap

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the longer comment bug be fixed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21164/can-the-longer-comment-bug-be-fixed)

Recently I noticed that comment with one line includes one extra blank line's space, have a look at to the following image for more clarification,

> [image]

In the above image all last three comments with one line is actually leaving one extra blank line. The comment line which has two or more lines looks perfect ( blue one ). I checked old posts and found same thing.

However when you looking at this image,

> [image]

It looks like a comment with few words only left one blank line, when you see my comment ( blue one ) is bigger than the above Patrick's and it is not leaving any blank space.

Is this bug or it has been designed like that?

Comment: Can you provide link to the post in the picture? I want to see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: @nhahtdh, sure [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147943/173001) but as i said it is there in all old posts too

Comment: Upvote a single-line comment and see what happens.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yeah, it removes that line,

Comment: @Lucifer: the free space is for the "upvote" and "flag" icons, if you can't upvote or flag (for example if you did before or it's your own comment), then that space won't be reserved.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, yeah, so it is `status-by-design`, thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you understand from the below image?

[image]

It's not a bug.

[As Joachim Sauer mentioned in his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147949/single-line-comment-leaves-one-lines-gap#comment424823_147949): The free space is for `upvote` and `flag` icons.

You can flag/vote comments added by other users. So you can see free space in one liner comments. But if you can't flag/vote any comment (e.g. your own comment or already flagged/voted comment), then that space won't be reserved for one liner comment.
(Here is my own example in the image.)